# creating a webpage for iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

i am creating a web page for iphone, i need the page to display efficiently in the iphone as well as on pc's. I'm coding in xhtml and uses support of JavaScript and css. The problem is that, i'm getting the correct view in the pc's but too small in the phone.how to adjust the size of the page. I am checking the user agent and loading a separate page (other than one for the pc) for the iphone. But i dont know hat changes are to be made to the attributes of body, inputs and other things so as to enable it to view correctly on the mobile browsers also

Comment: (its a simple suggestion) Don't feel anguish if you know this fact already ..
try adjusting the web-page resolution(size) to the Iphone's .. (you can read system wallpapers to get the exact resolution)

Comment: ya, this is what i'm looking for, but don't know to implement that thing(to change resolution), how to change the web page resolution?

Comment: Check out the iWebKit and i don't think you will be disappointed as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you making the same page for both devices? Usual practice is to make two separate pages that are optimised for both devices which by their nature have different form actors and characteristics.

so code along the lines of

```
$browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
if ($browser == true)  { header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/iphone/'); }
//else{echo 'just carry on';}
```

In terms of setting up the iPhone there are quite a few iPhone frameworks [see here for list](http://www.howitt.com/?p=196) around which will speed the development and if you are developing on a Mac with Snow Leopard and the latest SDK then there is now a built-in project in dashcode to produce one.

Comment: the basic need for me is to change the resolution of the web page to fit that of the iphone's screen size

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is helping you know as you already started to develop your page. But this kit is the ultimate kit for IPhone web as far as i know. Check it out.

[iWebKit](http://iwebkit.net/)